# startActivity() causing crash in Android

Tags: java, android

So I just started learning to develop Android apps, and I have a programming background (Python mainly), so I somewhat know what I'm doing. I'm having a problem with using startActivity(). I've commented code to figure out exactly where the error gets thrown, and it happens right as startActivity() is encountered. The error I get is from the emulator and it is just a popup window that says, "Unfortunately, Test has stopped." (Test is my program name) after I click my button. My code is this

```
package com.test.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class TestActivity extends Activity {

public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.test.test.MESSAGE";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }
    }

    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textBox1);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Now I know that won't do anything yet, but why is it crashing?
My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<EditText android:id="@+id/textBox1"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/textBox1Hint" />
<Button 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button1"
    android:onClick="sendMessage" />   

</LinearLayout>
```

My manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.test.test"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".TestActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity" >
    </activity>

</application>
</manifest>
```

I saw that a lot of other people were having problems with this because they had not declared their activities in the manifest, but I think I have done so properly. Any help would be so greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide the log cat having the error for same....

Comment: i think don't need to use intent .. you just staying in your activity .also you didn't declare target activity.

Comment: Sorry, I believe I confused a lot of you by not posting my entire code. That or I'm confused about what I'm being told. I updated the code in my initial question just now if you could take a look again please.

Comment: @user1392894 use separate file for classes. Is main.xml used for both activity? Why are you using  setContentView inside sendMessage? Where are you calling sendMessage? You need to clarify these things IMHO.

Comment: Yes, main.xml is used for both activities. sendMessage is being called because I want to do something with the information in the textbox after the button is clicked.

Comment: @Imran Rana Hey thanks a lot. I seperated the classes into different files, and everything seems to be working fine now :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use separate files for **TestActivity** and **DisplayMessageActivity** classes. In your given code you are not specifying a layout for your **DisplayMessageActivity** activity using **setContentView**.

Answer (score 2):

One possible problem is that

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textBox1);
```

returns `null` because you dont set anywhere the layout for your activity (with `setContentView`)

If your `editetext` is included in `view` (passed to `sendMessage`), you can find it with

```
EditText editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.textBox1);
```

Comment: Tried modifying that, and it did not solve the problem, but thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think problem is you are on DisplayMessageActivity and starting the same activity.
What you need to do is start test activity and call DisplayMessageActivity  from intent.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is this,
you declare in the manifest that the main class is TestActivity:

```
<activity
    android:name=".TestActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

but you wanted to start DisplayMessageActivity,
so, change this to the following:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
@Override
```

Comment: Sorry, I believe I confused a lot of you by not posting my entire code. That or I'm confused about what I'm being told. I updated the code in my initial question just now if you could take a look again please.

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand what you are actually trying to achieve by starting the same activity again. Try this,

```
    public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {
    private  String message ;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setLayout(R.layout.<name of the xml file> ); // change the name if it is not in layout folder
           EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textBox1);
           String message = editText.getText().toString();
           Button submitBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
           submitBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                     Toast toast = Toast.makeText(DisplayMessageActivity.this,
                                message,
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        toast.show();
    }});
        }
    }
```

The above code simply displays the String, This is just a sample code... Hope that helps!!!

**EDIT**
To run this code you must also add id tag to your Button Tag inside XML file having value button1..

Answer (score 0):

Actullay you have created the Activity inside activity. Which is not much pref-able but if want to stick with that then you have to change the  android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity" to

Comment: may in android:name=".TestActivity$DisplayMessageActivity" to